# Facebook OAuth Login Bug in Ionic

Tags: angular, cordova, firebase, ionic2, firebase-authentication

I am using Facebook Auth for my Ionic app, and am doing the authenticating with the Firebase module. I believe that I have set up the firebase module properly, but I keep encountering an error when I am trying to log in. I will point out that the log-in method has worked once when testing on the web browser and has since then produced the following bug. I have tried testing on an android emulator since to mixed results (buggy builds). Here is my code.

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import  firebase  from 'firebase';
import { Facebook } from '@ionic-native/facebook';
//import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { HomePage } from '../home/home';
/**
 * Generated class for the LoginPage page.
 *
 * See http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info
 * on Ionic pages and navigation.
 */
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html',
})
export class LoginPage {

  homePage = HomePage;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public facebook: Facebook) {
  }


  login2(){
    //this.navCtrl.setRoot(this.homePage);
    let provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
    firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider).then(() => {
      firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then((result) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
        this.navCtrl.push(this.homePage)

      })

    }).catch(function(error){
      console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    });


  }


}
```

The template is basically just a button with (click)='login2()'.
When I click this button, the program crashes and reloads with error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dataset' of null
    at HTMLDocument.r (bundle.js:6112)
r @ bundle.js:6112

This only happens when I click this button so I know that it has something to do with the way that I am using firebase. I figure that maybe that these firebase methods require cordova (and thus don't work unless building natively, if I'm not mistaken) or there is some extra setup required that I am missing (like making sure the firebase 'database' is already assigned to a listener or something in app.module). Another theory I have is that, since it worked once, it is still maintaining that it is already logged in and runs into some strange error due to that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `signInWithRedirect()` like that in Cordova environments, you have two choices, you can either:

1. Use the native Facebook plugin and then pass the credential to Firebase like this: https://javebratt.com/ionic-2-facebook-login/
2. You need to install a bunch of Cordova plugins to get the redirect to work, like this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/cordova

Hope it helps :)

Comment: ok, would either of these methods work when running in web browser (with ionic serve)? From my understanding, the cordova-specific stuff isn't available unless working on a native device. If not, what can I use as a substitute when not running natively?

Comment: If you want to do it in a web browser then this is the one you need: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/facebook-login

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me, maybe it will help you:

```
facebookSignIn(){
    let provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
    firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider);
    firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then((user) => {
      console.log("Successful facebook sign-in!");
      this.navCtrl.setRoot('HomePage');
    }).catch((error) => {
      alert(error.message);
    });
  }
```

Comment: I've changed it to this and now I can see the transition to HomePage but then the app restarts itself... Though this time without the error message. However, it doesn't prompt me for login credentials... but still treats it as a success? I will try performing a logout on page load & some other things.

Comment: What is your application flow? Do you redirect the user to the sign-in page if the user is not logged in? If yes, how do you do that?

Comment: I just go to login page on start-up. Im running with ionic serve so I figured that the browser wouldn't save the login credentials but I'm not sure if that is true. Should I do that? I do something with user in app.component right?

Comment: You can check if the signed-in user is saved by verifying it in local storage. In Chrome, while your app is running, go to Application > Storage > local storage. There, u should see some stored data in firebase:authUser:id, which is the user's information.